# pull selected objects out of array to create another array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have a use case where it's necessary to create an array of objects given 2 other arrays.  The `eligibleScenarios` array contains the names of the scenarios to be isolated from the array of all `scenarios`.

```
const eligibleScenarios = ["budget 26", "planning 47", "budget 58"];

const scenarios = [
  {"name": "budget 26", "exported": "2020-04-30"},
  {"name": "budget 27", "exported": "2020-05-01"},
  {"name": "budget 28", "exported": "2020-05-01"},
  {"name": "planning 43", "exported": "2020-04-30"},
  {"name": "planning 47", "exported": "2020-04-30"},
  {"name": "budget 55", "exported": "2020-05-04"},
  {"name": "budget 57", "exported": "2020-05-04"},
  {"name": "budget 58", "exported": "2020-05-04"},
  {"name": "budget 59", "exported": "2020-05-05"}
];
```

I have tried this:

```
const matches = scenarios.find(o => eligibleScenarios.includes(o.name));
console.log(matches);
```

But it results in a single object like this:
`{ name: "budget 26", exported: "2020-04-30" }`

What I need to generate is this:

```
[
 {"name": "budget 26", "exported": "2020-04-30"},
 {"name": "planning 47", "exported": "2020-04-30"},
 {"name": "budget 58", "exported": "2020-05-04"}
]
```

How can this be achieved without using 3rd party libraries?  Also, if there's a way to keep it concise, similar to how `matches` is now, that would be ideal (ie. avoid big blocks of looping code).

Comment: There is a great tutorial at "https://javascript.info/array-methods", which explains array methods very nicely. You will find your answer. Have a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `.find` as it only returns the first result. Use [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead.

```js
const eligibleScenarios = ["budget 26", "planning 47", "budget 58"];

const scenarios = [
  {"name": "budget 26", "exported": "2020-04-30"},
  {"name": "budget 27", "exported": "2020-05-01"},
  {"name": "budget 28", "exported": "2020-05-01"},
  {"name": "planning 43", "exported": "2020-04-30"},
  {"name": "planning 47", "exported": "2020-04-30"},
  {"name": "budget 55", "exported": "2020-05-04"},
  {"name": "budget 57", "exported": "2020-05-04"},
  {"name": "budget 58", "exported": "2020-05-04"},
  {"name": "budget 59", "exported": "2020-05-05"}
];

const matches = scenarios.filter(o => eligibleScenarios.includes(o.name));
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: I am suspicious on ```Array.includes``` performance, I don't know.

Comment: @VahidAlimohamadi so - that wasn't the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter` and `Set.prototype.has` to do this.

Using the `Set.prototype.has` method achieves a `O(1)` look up:

```js
eligibleScenarios = new Set(["budget 26", "planning 47", "budget 58"]);

const scenarios = [
  {"name": "budget 26", "exported": "2020-04-30"},
  {"name": "budget 27", "exported": "2020-05-01"},
  {"name": "budget 28", "exported": "2020-05-01"},
  {"name": "planning 43", "exported": "2020-04-30"},
  {"name": "planning 47", "exported": "2020-04-30"},
  {"name": "budget 55", "exported": "2020-05-04"},
  {"name": "budget 57", "exported": "2020-05-04"},
  {"name": "budget 58", "exported": "2020-05-04"},
  {"name": "budget 59", "exported": "2020-05-05"}
];

const result = scenarios.filter(s => eligibleScenarios.has(s.name));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I would like to know the reasoning behind the downvote too.  The code snippet for this answer contains the correct result.

Comment: @knot22 In my opinion a `Set` would be better option than `Array` to test lookups. `Set` always has a `O(1)` performance when searching for the element while for an Array it would be `O(n)`.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const scenarios = [
  {"name": "budget 26", "exported": "2020-04-30"},
  {"name": "budget 27", "exported": "2020-05-01"},
  {"name": "budget 28", "exported": "2020-05-01"},
  {"name": "planning 43", "exported": "2020-04-30"},
  {"name": "planning 47", "exported": "2020-04-30"},
  {"name": "budget 55", "exported": "2020-05-04"},
  {"name": "budget 57", "exported": "2020-05-04"},
  {"name": "budget 58", "exported": "2020-05-04"},
  {"name": "budget 59", "exported": "2020-05-05"}
];

let myFilter=(list, names)=> {
  if (!names) return list;
  !Array.isArray(names) && (names=[names]);

  let query = names.reduce((r,n,index)=>{
    return `${r} ${!!index ? ' ||' : ''} s.name==='${n}'`
  },'');

  return scenarios.filter(s=>eval(query))
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(myFilter(scenarios,'planning 43'),null,2));

console.log(JSON.stringify(myFilter(scenarios,['budget 58','budget 26', 'planning 37']),null,2));
```

This is only the simple query based on name, It can be more flexible and ...